# how can I convert the following text to binary and readable text? and in what form is it written?

Tags: python, binary, hex

so I have the following text:

> '\x56\x10\x34\xf8'

According to the assignment I got, this is written in hex. however, I can't convert this into readable text or binary using the unhexlify function from the binascii library (python).

So I guess this is a three part question:
I would really appreciate if someone could identify in which form this text is written, give a brief explanation about it (or give a link that explains it) and give a code that converts it from it's current form to binary and readable text.

Comment: I guess I should be a little more specific with my request. I want to convert it into binary in order to use xor operation to encrypt it, and then convert the encrypted binary sequence into text. so really what I am looking for is a way to convert it from hex to binary

Answer (score 2):

This is hex representation of ascii text.
In python, anything with a `'\x'` is a hex character, with the 2 digits after that representing its value.
`'\x41'` represents the capital 'A' character

You can turn most of the characters into standard ascii using a `str()` call however some hex numbers do not map to readable ascii characters, for example `'\x10'` maps to the new line character `'\n'`.

However strings formatted in this way would not act any differently if they were in their ascii counterparts. The string '\x54\x47\x47\x19' can be indexed or printed. index 0 would return '\x54' and index 1 would return '\x47'. Converting it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! by capital a do you mean that if I convert it into an integer an than into ascii it would be an A?

Comment: yes, you can search up the ascii conversions of hex digits online

Comment: Ok, so one last thing, is it possible to convert it straight from hex to binary in python?

Comment: Yes, using the bin() command you can convert a number in from hex to binary

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those values map to ASCII character values, you should be able to loop over those values (possibly converting to `int`) and then feed them into `chr(val)` to obtain the corresponding character.